# Getting the instance name as an NSString

Tags: objective-c

Lets say I have created some class called Rectangle. I create a mutable array (called allRectangles) and add four different rectangles to the array:

ex:

```
Rectangle *rect1 = [[Rectangle alloc] init];
[allRectangles addObject: rect1];
```

...repeated for rect2, rect3 and rect4

If I iterate through the array using
`for (Rectangle *rect in allRectangles)` and I simply want to output the name of each one, how do I do this? For example if I do:

```
NSLog(@"%@", rect)
```

it will print the class name and the memory address. I want it to print rect1 then rect2 and so on... please help???

Comment: Add name variable to rectangle class?

Comment: Once your code is compiled, the original variable names are lost. The best thing to do would be to give your Rectangle class a `name` property as juniperi suggests. Either that, or store your Rectangles in a dictionary using keys to identify them (although, which this approach you lose the order of objects, but you could use a combination of stores).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The objects in your code snippet don't have names, at least not as far as you've shown. That is, the `Rectangle` class doesn't seem to have a `name` property or anything like that.

I suspect you're confusing the variable name (e.g. `rect1`) with the name of the object. They are not the same thing. `rect1` is a pointer variable which points to an object (an instance of the `Rectangle` class) but that fact doesn't affect the object. An object may be pointed to by many different variables over the course of its lifetime but that doesn't mean that the names of any of those variables is the name of the object. (Notice that in your for-in loop, each object is pointed to by the variable `rect`. Do you expect that fact to cause the object to be named "rect"?)

If you want an object to have a name like "rect1", then you need to add a `name` property to the class and set that property on each object you create.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you store elements in an `NSDictionary` instead of an `NSArray` and retrieve them by the name of the variable?

```objc
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary new] ;   

Rectangle *rect1 = [[Rectangle alloc] init];
[dict setObject:rect1 forKey:@"rect1"];


for (NSString *key in [dict allKeys]) {
    NSLog(@"%@ => %@", key, [dict objectForKey:key]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The local variable name is source code information, it doesn't exist in your running code, it does even make much sense what is the 'rectangle name' in the following

```
Rectangle * rect1 = [[Rectangle alloc] init];
Rectangle * rect2 = rect1;
```

rect1 or rect2

If you want you rectangles to have a name you have to give them a name property and set it when you create each rectangle.